# Ошибка при запуске web приложения

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack, ruby

при запуске веб приложения на локальном хосте, выдаёт ошибку, я предположил что webpack не может найти главный js файл от которого отталкивается всё приложения, подскажите пожалуйста что можно сделать? webpack запущен в фоне другой консоли. (так же там в фоне запущены некоторые базы данных в докере, по идее это ведь никак не влияет)[image: на картинке вывод ошибки при попытке запуска приложения]

Comment: yarn install без ошибок прошел?